# Prevent the user from submitting data in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent the user from submitting data in a form, but when I test it with JavaScript it's not returning true.

I'm using a method where I set the type of the submit button as `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`: `<input type="button" name="envoyer" onclick="valider(this.form)">`

and then I use this JavaScript script:

```
function valider(formulaire)
        {
            if(//my test)
            {
                formulaire.envoyer.type = "submit";
                formulaire.envoyer.submit();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Is there any other method of leaving the submit button without changing it's type to button?

Comment: are you using Jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal Javascript

you can use return value of function to prevent form submission

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
```

and function like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMyForm()
{
  if(check if your conditions are not satisfying)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    returnToPreviousPage();
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
</script>
```

In jQuery

```
$('#form').submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

In DOJO

```
dojo.connect(form, "onsubmit", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the function to the form's submit event. You don't need to change the input type:

```
myForm.submit = function valider(formulaire)
        {
            if(//my test)
            {
                formulaire.envoyer.type = "submit";
                formulaire.envoyer.submit();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why change the type of the button?

Just do `onclick="return valider(this.form)"`. Returning false will prevent the submission.